# How do I run nyc merge from Makefile?

Tags: makefile, istanbul, nyc

I've inherited a JS code base with Jasmine unit tests. The testing framework uses `karma` and `instanbul-combine` to get code coverage. It seems `istanbul-combine` isn't working with present node modules, and besides is no longer maintained: the recommended replacement is `nyc`. I'm having trouble replacing `istanbul-combine` with `nyc` in the `Makefile`.

Here's are my attempts at merging the data (not even trying to get a report yet):

#1

```
@for dir in $(shell ls -d coverage/*/); do \
    echo "Merging $${dir}"; \
    npx nyc merge $${dir} coverage-final.json; \
done
```

#2

```
npx nyc merge coverage coverage-final.json
```

#3

```
npx nyc merge --include coverage/*/ coverage-final.json
```

The coverage data is in `coverage/*/coverage-final.json`, but none of these attempts succeeds in mergeing it into the result file `coverage-final.json`.

With #1, I'm pretty sure it's only actually merging a single set of results into the result file. With #2, there's an error; but if I put that command in the shell CLI, nothing is put into the result file.

With #3, at least there's no error, but only one of the coverage files is merged.

---

Here's the original Makefile line that I'm replacing:

```
PATH=$(PROJECT_HOME)/bin:$$PATH node_modules/istanbul-combine/cli.js \
    -d coverage/summary -r html \
    coverage/*/coverage-final.json
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little script in the Makefile to copy the `coverage-final.json` files from the child directories of the `coverage` directory to the `coverage` directory itself, and then merge them into a `coverage-final.json` file in the main JS directory.

```
@cd coverage; \
 for dir in $(dir */coverage-final.json); do \
        fn="$${dir}coverage-final.json"; \
    newName="$${dir::-1}.json"; \
    echo "cp $${fn} $${newName}"; \
    cp $$fn $$newName; \
done;
npx nyc merge coverage coverage-final.json
```

The new filenames of the individual coverage files are taken from the name of the directories from which they come.