# How to generate nyc report from json results (no .nyc_output)?

Tags: istanbul, nyc

I've inherited a JS code base with Jasmine unit tests. The testing framework uses `karma` and `instanbul-combine` to get code coverage. It seems `istanbul-combine` isn't working with present node modules, and besides is no longer maintained: the recommended replacement is `nyc`. I'm having trouble replacing `istanbul-combine` with `nyc` in the `Makefile`.

I succeeded in merging my separate coverage results (json) files into a single `coverage-final.json` file ([this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61530631/how-do-i-run-nyc-merge-from-makefile)), but now I need to generate the summary report.

How do I generate a summary report from a `coverage.json` file?

One problem here, I think, is that I have no `.nyc_output` directory with intermediate results, since I'm not using `nyc` to generate coverage data. All my coverage data is in a `coverage` directory and its child directories.

I've tried specifying a filename:

```
npx nyc report --include coverage-final.json
```

Also tried specifying the directory:

```
npx nyc report --include coverage
```

Neither works.

```
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

The CLI help documentation says

```
  --temp-dir, -t          directory to read raw coverage information from
```

But when I use that point to `coverage` directory (viz., `npx nyc report -t coverage`), I get the same unsatisfactory result. NYC is apparently fairly rigid in the formats it will accept this data.

---

Here's the original Makefile line that I'm replacing:

```
PATH=$(PROJECT_HOME)/bin:$$PATH node_modules/istanbul-combine/cli.js \
    -d coverage/summary -r html \
    coverage/*/coverage-final.json
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using this line in my Makefile worked:

```
npx nyc report --reporter html --reporter text -t coverage --report-dir coverage/summary
```

It grabs the JSON files from the `coverage` directory and puts them altogether into an HTML report in the `coverage/summary` subdirectory. (Didn't need the `nyc merge` command from my previous question/answer.)

I'm not sure why the `-t` option didn't work before. It may be I was using the wrong version of `nyc` (15.0.0 instead of 14.1.1, fwiw).

Answer (score 6):

After trying multiple nyc commands to produce the report from JSON with no luck, I found an interesting behavior of nyc: **You have to be in the parent directory of the instrumented code when you are generating a report.** For example:
If the code I instrumented is in `/usr/share/node/**`, and the merged `coverage.json` result is in `/tmp` directory. If I run `nyc report --temp-dir=/tmp --reporter=text` under `/tmp`, I won't get anything.

```
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

But if I run the same command under `/usr/share/node` or `/`, I'm able to get the correct output with coverage numbers.
Not sure if it's a weird permission issue in nyc. If it's an expected behavior of nyc

Comment: Yu can also do it like this:
```
npx nyc report --reporter=text-summary --cwd <pah to parent of src> -t <path to .nyc_output>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to pass `--exclude-after-remap=false` to generate a report from Typescript integration tests and unit tests coverage json files:

```
npx nyc report --reporter html --reporter text -t coverage --report-dir coverage/summary --exclude-after-remap false
```