# Merging coverage reports from nyc

Tags: sonarqube, mocha.js, code-coverage, nyc

I have a CI running that does mocha test executions in parallel. A test execution creates a coverage report `coverage.json` - generated by `nyc`. I want to have a final merged report from all of the `coverage.json`s in lcov format, but I can't manage to generate one - I always end up having an empty text summary. What I've tried:

1. Running `nyc report`:

```
nyc report --temp-dir=nyc/coverage_dir --reporter=text --reporter=lcov
```

gives an empty report and text summary

2. First running `nyc merge` and then `nyc report`

```
nyc merge ./coverage_dir coverage.json
nyc report --report-dir=temp --reporter=text --reporter=lcov
```

This combination does seem to merge the coverage.jsons files, at least judging from the file size, but the `report` step still displays an empty text summary.

3. Trying the above with different version, i.e. `nyc 15.1.0` and `nyc 14.1.1`
4. Specifying the `-t` flag and `--report-dir` options outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61643904/2529672)
5. Changing to a parent directory and rerunning the commands as specified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63513947/2529672).

All resulting in an empty text summary of the final report.

Answer (score 4):

I solved it in this way.

Copy all the json files in the default folder:

```
mkdir .nyc_output
cp project_a/coverage/coverage-final.json .nyc_output/project_a.json
cp project_b/coverage/coverage-final.json .nyc_output/project_b.json
```

Then generate the report:

```
nyc report --reporter=text --reporter=lcov --report-dir=destination-dir
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there is now a section in nyc doc about it: [combining-reports-from-multiple-runs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nyc#combining-reports-from-multiple-runs)