# Can nyc generate a combined coverage report, that shows which individual reports cover which part of the file?

Tags: code-coverage, nyc

I'm converting Mocha tests to Jest, and want to maintain coverage

I have figured out how to combine coverage, based on [Merging coverage reports from nyc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65381232/merging-coverage-reports-from-nyc) and some other similar questions.

However, when combining the two `.json` files, the numbers are just added up.

Here's a mock up of what I'm imagining:

[image: html test coverage report showing 6 files, the bar showing coverage percentage for four of the six files has a black line showing the split between different]

I don't think this is possible.

I've looked at the generated reports, the code used to combine coverage and hunted around the docs and issues for nyc.

But on the off chance I missed something, I thought I'd ask here.

Is this, or something very similar, possible?